# Why does my custom rmsle_loss produce negative scores during cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation, scoring

I have a pipeline and scorer that produces some unexpected behaviors during cross-validation. During cross validation the pipeline produces all negative scores, but from the definition from rmsle_loss and rmsle_score should these not always produce positive scores regardless of the data (split)?

```
model = XGBRegressor(eval_metric=rmsle_loss, tree_method='hist')

ttr = TransformedTargetRegressor(
    regressor=model,
    func=np.log1p, 
    inverse_func=np.expm1,
    check_inverse=False,
)

pl = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessing', preprocessing),
    ('ttr', ttr)
])

cross_val_score(
    estimator=pl,
    X=train,
    y=train[target], 
    scoring=rmsle_loss, 
    cv=tss,
    n_jobs=1,
)
```

The definition of the loss and scorer function:

```
def rmsle_score(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Calculate the Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error (RMSLE) metric.

    Parameters:
    - y_true: Array-like, true values.
    - y_pred: Array-like, predicted values.

    Returns:
    - rmsle: Float, RMSLE score.
    """
    # Convert inputs to numpy arrays
    y_true = np.array(y_true)
    y_pred = np.array(y_pred)

    # Apply logarithm to both true and predicted values
    log_true = np.log1p(y_true)
    log_pred = np.log1p(y_pred)

    # Calculate squared difference between log-transformed values
    squared_diff = (log_pred - log_true) ** 2

    # Calculate mean squared difference
    mean_squared_log_error = np.mean(squared_diff)

    # Calculate RMSLE score by taking the square root
    rmsle = np.sqrt(mean_squared_log_error)

    return rmsle

# create a custom RMLSE scorer
rmsle_loss = make_scorer(score_func=rmsle_score, greater_is_better=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, that you set `greater_is_better=False` in `make_scorer`.

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) about `greater_is_better`:

> Whether `score_func` is a score function (default), meaning high is good, or a loss function, meaning low is good. In the latter case, the scorer object will sign-flip the outcome of the `score_func`.

This means, that for loss functions, i.e. a function that you try to minimize (`greater_is_better=False`), the loss function output is multiplied by -1 to get the actual scorer output.

By flipping the sign, `make_scorer` always results in a scorer, where greater values are better.

Comment: Besides the point, but: 
From the [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer](documentation) about greater_is_better:

> Whether score_func is a score function (default), meaning high is good, or a loss function, meaning low is good. In the latter case, the scorer object will sign-flip the outcome of the score_func.

Comment: You are right, I did not quote enough. Without following the link, the quote is not understandable. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Tim: is it now better?

Comment: I omitted to thank you for your reply. It made me realize, I made an error in the naming and use of the loss function and the scorer. 'rmsle_score' is not a score, but rather a loss function. And what is currently defined as 'rmsle_loss' should be more correctly named 'rmsle_scorer'. Although, would I not need the 'rmsle_scorer' to use the negative of the 'rmsle_loss' for everything to work correctly? 

I will verify in the near future, but currently I'ṁ in the process of refactoring some code, which prevents me from testing. But thanks again!

Comment: For the internal processes for sklearn, a scorer need to be a score where greater values are better. For this reasons, make_scorer flips the sign of loss function. If you want to use the loss values later on, you would need to flip the sign back by your own, after sklearn computed and used them